# Proof of the inequality of a convex/concave function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, convex-analysis

In the following [article](https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/cv1/t), a proof for the inequality of a convex/concave function is given. In the proof, they define $h_{a,b}$ as the segment joining two points in the convex/concave function. They state that $h_{a,b}$ is a linear function, and, accordingly, they proceed to use the two properties of a linear function namely: $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$  $$f(ax)=af(x)$$

However, how can they be certain that the line that extends through the $h_{a,b}$ segment is a linear function and not an affine function (in the latter case it wouldn't make the two properties usable since we would have $f(0)\neq 0$)

Comment: $h_{a,b}$ is affine and defined for all $\lambda$. Where in the article do you think they are using the above formulae for $f$???

Comment: They say, and I quote: the fact that $h_{a,b}$ is linear means that: $$h_{a,b}((1-\lambda )a +\lambda b) = (1-\lambda)f(a) + \lambda f(b)$$

Comment: The term linear is often (unfortunately) used for affine. $h_{a,b}$ is affine and it passes through the points $(a,f(a)), (b,f(b))$ so it **must** have the above formula. This has **nothing** to do with $f$ as such.

Comment: well to arrive to the above equality, you would have to use the two properties of a **linear** function. I'm assuming they used $$h_{a,b}(a+b)=h_{a,b}(a)+h_{a,b}(b)$$ $$h_{a,b}((1-\lambda)a)=(1-\lambda) h_{a,b}(a)$$ and $$h_{a,b}(\lambda b)= \lambda h_{a,b}(b)$$ To conclude that $$h_{a,b}((1-\lambda)a +\lambda b)=(1-\lambda )h_{a,b}(a)+\lambda h_{a,b}(b)$$ Those are properties of a linear not an affine function right ?

Comment: Sorry I just realized I inadvertently used $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ as a substitute for $h_{a,b}(a)$ and $h_{a,b}(b)$ in first comment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing. Just define $h_{a,b}$ in whatever way you want to it passes through the points $(a,f(a)), (b,f(b))$.

Comment: what i'm doing is trying to understand why the above equality holds since $h_{a,b}$ is an affine not a linear function

Comment: A function is affine **iff** $h(tx+(1-t)y) = t h(x) + (1-t) h(y)$ for all $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are defining an affine function $h$ on the line joining the points $a,b$ such that
$h(a) = f(a)$, $h(b) = f(b)$.

Since $h$ is affine, it satisfies
$h(tx+(1-t)y) = th(x)+(1-t) h(y)$ for all $x,y$ on the line $a,b$ and all $t$.

In particular, if we pick $x=a,y=b$ we have
$h(ta+(1-t)b) = th(a)+(1-t)h(b)$. Since we have $h(a) = f(a)$, $h(b) = f(b)$, we must have
$h(ta+(1-t)b) = tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)$.

Comment: Obviously, if an affine function is defined as such (which I didn't know before) then everything would make sense. At first, I was dubious about the equality you used to define an affine function, but it seems like it works when I verified it using a simple example. I will still need to find a proof for how it was derived... If you have any resource where I can find a proof for it, then could you please share it? Otherwise, I'll just accept your answer

Comment: There are various ways of defining an affine function, I am not near my library, but I would guess something like Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis" could would have a definition. A simpler (and equivalent) definition is that $h$ is affine **iff** it can be written as a linear function plus a constant. In that case, you would start with $h(x) = Ax+h_0$ and use the constraints $h(a)=f(a), h(b)=f(b)$ to derive $A,h_0$.